# UnitTests: UserManager<ApplicationUser> Mock Setup FindByIdAsync Returns NULL

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit

In my test project i am using **xUnit** with **Moq**,
in my controller test class i also need an object of type `Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>` to get the current user informations.

That's why i am using **Moq** to **Setup** the async method `FindByIdAsync` the setup is configured like this :

```
public async Task EntrsAdd_ShouldReturnSuccessJsonResult_WhenModelIdIsNull()
{
    //Arrange
    var id = _fixture.Create<string>();
    ApplicationUser applicationUserMock = _fixture.Create<ApplicationUser>();
    var viewModelMock = _fixture.Create<AddOrUpdateEntrViewModel>();
    viewModelMock.Id = null;
    _userManager.Setup(u => u.FindByIdAsync(id))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult<ApplicationUser>(applicationUserMock));

    //Act
    var result = await _sutEntrsController.Add(viewModelMock).ConfigureAwait(false);
    int test = 0;
    //Assert
}
```

the method i am testing in the controller is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddOrUpdateEntrViewModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UsrId);

    var entr = _mapper.Map<Entr>(model);
    entr.Usr = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}";

    if (model.Id is null)
    {
        await _entrService.AddAsync(entr);
    }
    else
    {
        await _entrService.UpdateAsync(entr);
    }

    return new JsonResult("success.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the setup uses the `id` variable and the corresponding property in the viewmodel is not set.

Either set the correct id for `UsrId` on the `ViewModelMock` or *relax* the setup by using `It.IsAny<string>()`:

```
var viewModelMock = _fixture.Create<AddOrUpdateEntrViewModel>();
viewModelMock.Id = null;
viewModelMock.UsrId = id;
```

or

```
_userManager.Setup(u => u.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<ApplicationUser>(applicationUserMock));
```

Comment: thank you so much i did not pay attention, my bad, changed it to :
`_userManager.Setup(u => u.FindByIdAsync(viewModelMock.UsrId))` because it tells me that `viewModelMock.UsrId` is what the `FindByIdAsync` needs, however the `It.IsAny<string>()` because it's cleaner and works perfectly.

Thank you so much Markus

Comment: @KARIMYassine you're welcome. `It.IsAny<T>()` is more open in comparison to the first version, depends on how strict you want to test.